# Why the vscode tree view file item has a larger indentation than it should be?

Tags: treeview, vscode-extensions

I am currently developing an Vscode Extension, it uses TreeView. 
The TreeView works fine, but it has one problem:

Why the vscode tree view file item has a **larger indentation** than it should be? 
(folder item seems have correct indentation)

Is there any config I missed? Or what are the potential causes?

---

As graph shows:
[image: indentation]
[image: chrome dev tool]

---

(for the code, its complex, not worth showing; I may update a easier one later.)

---

---

***Update:***

1. I made another `simpler Normal Tree View`, and the indentation is indeed there 
   -- its: file's icon is aligned with the folder's icon  
   -- its not: file's icon is aligned with the folder's `>` arrow
2. but, mine's indentation is still even larger than that `Normal one`, Idk why 
   -- file's icon is aligned with the folder's icon + more to the right
3. I tried & found that **the missing of `align-icon-with-twisty` css class** is the key, but I have no idea why its missing (see graph) 
   [image: align-icon-with-twisty css class]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remove the parent folder's icon** fixed the indent problem.

(no idea why)

Comment: I guess having an icon on the root item will always reserve icon space in all child items too.